# I want to set an environment variable to my java application while bootstrapping such that the jars in classpath can read it

Tags: java, server, helidon

I have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH such that one of the jar in my classpath uses that to execute some native java files.

I have tried setting up the environment file to my server while bootstrapping, but
System.getenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) is given as null.

Comment: have you exported the variable before executing?

Comment: yes i have tried exporting the variable via Environment file of server. Also, i tried, "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/ java -jar <>"

Comment: i do not see the export keyword

Answer (score 0):

Library path in use by Java is shown by `System.getProperty("java.library.path")`. Just print the value in your app when you run it.

```
java ... your.App
```

Note the value and edit LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running a second time:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/blahblah
# or export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/blahblah:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
java ... your.App
```

You should see the changed "java.library.path" now prefixed with `/blahblah:`.